# How to select and deselect group of options in jquery multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I know I can pass `'checkAll'` and `'uncheckAll'` to my multiselect instance, but how do I deselect a group of options?

```
var deselectOptions = [1, 2, 3];

$('#my_select').multiselect('checkAll'); //except deselect options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for checking all except:

```
var deselectOptions = [1, 2, 3];

$('#my_select').multiselect('checkAll');

$('#my_select :selected').each(function () {
    if (deselectOptions.includes(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
    }
});

$('#my_select').multiselect('refresh');
```

or the opposite:

```
var selectOptions = [1, 2, 3];

//may not be required depending on use case
$('#my_select').multiselect('uncheckAll');

$('#my_select option').each(function () {
    if (selectOptions.includes(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    }
});

$('#my_select').multiselect('refresh');
```